# IOS objective C write function with completionBlock

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

Hi I'm writing a `function` to call and API and get the `response` then store to `coredata` entity (Using magical record). My method simple take no input and return nothing (only call api and store data to `entity`. My purpose is to execute completionBlock code when `success` and log an `error` (so that can call the function in a `viewController`. I'm still don't know how to write it properly. Anyhelp is much appreciate.

My Apiclient

```
    typedef void (^ApiClientSuccess)(id responseObject);
    typedef void (^ApiClientFailure)(NSError *error);

 - (void)getSingpostContentsOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure {

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@singpost-contents.php",CMS_BASE_URL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:GET_METHOD URLString:urlString parameters:nil error:nil];

    [self sendJSONRequest:request success:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject) {
        success(responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        failure(error);
        [self reportAPIIssueURL:[request.URL absoluteString] payload:nil message:[error description]];
    }];
}
```

My function (need to write it properly) so that I can call and write some code when function complete execute

```
+ (void)API_SingPostContentOnCompletion:(void)completionBlock {

    [[ApiClient sharedInstance] getSingpostContentsOnSuccess:^(id responseJSON) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_rootSavingContext];
            [responseJSON[@"root"] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id attributes, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                Content *content = [Content MR_findFirstOrCreateByAttribute:@"name" withValue:attributes[@"Name"] inContext:localContext];
                content.content = attributes[@"content"];
            }];

            [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL contextDidSave, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                if (error) NSLog(@"Error save content to persistentStore");

            }];

//            if (completionBlock) {
//                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//                    completionBlock();
//                });
//            }
        });
    } onFailure:^(NSError *error) {
//        if (completionBlock) {
//            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//                completionBlock(nil);
//            });
//        }
        NSLog(@"Failed to get SingPost Content");
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the blocks :

```
  typedef void (^ SuccessBlock)(BOOL success, id response);
  typedef void (^ FailureBlock)(NSError *error, NSInteger statusCode);
```

Write the method that use these blocks, for example for a simple AFNetworking POST call:

```
+ (void)myFunction:(NSString*)function  success:(SuccessBlock)success failure:(FailureBlock)failure{

   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        ....
   [manager POST:functionURL parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            if (operation.response.statusCode == 201 || operation.response.statusCode == 200) {
                success(YES,responseObject);
            }else{
                 success(NO,responseObject);
            }
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            failure(error, operation.response.statusCode);
        }];
  }
```

and you can call your method from other class:

```
[YourClass myFunction:@""  success:^(BOOL success, id response) {
       if(success){
            //my call is success
       }
    } failure:^(NSError *error, NSInteger statusCode) {

    }];
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to write as yrs suggest. in mean time i have manage to write like this: + (void)API_SingPostContentOnCompletion:(void (^) (BOOL success))completionBlock { }. Is this can be used?

Comment: If you declare block as typedef void, then you dont have to use void ^ ( ...in the method as param. If you want to pass the direct declaration then you can do something like:  - (void)myFunction:(void (^)(id, int))myBlock;

Comment: Is the AFNetworking you wrote above is for 2.x I'm using for 3.x may be need some change accordingly?